# Alt Stack is not working as expected

Tags: script

I have a scenario as follows:

- In a company, there is a manager and three employees. The multisig signature will be redeemed by the manager combined with one of the employees.
- However, only the manager, or only the employees with enough number of signatures will not be able to redeem the transaction
- The order of the signatures should not matter
- Assume my_public_key is manager_public_key

My solution was: `[OP_2DUP, my_public_key, OP_CHECKSIG, OP_IF, OP_DROP, OP_ELSE, my_public_key, OP_CHECKSIGVERIFY, OP_SWAP, OP_ENDIF, OP_DROP, OP_1, employee1_public_key, employee2_public_key, employee3_public_key, OP_3, OP_CHECKMULTISIG]`

So I tried to shorten the script in order to have less bit in a transaction by using alt-stack.

My suggested solution is just to duplicate the my_public_key and push it into the alt-stack and whenever I need it later, I can pop it from the alt-stack and use it. So by the final script I should deduct the script by one public key.

Suggested solution: `[OP_2DUP, my_public_key, OP_DUP, OP_TOALTSTACK, OP_CHECKSIG, OP_IF, OP_DROP, OP_ELSE, OP_FROMALTSTACK, OP_CHECKSIGVERIFY, OP_SWAP, OP_ENDIF, OP_DROP, OP_1, employee1_public_key, employee2_public_key, employee3_public_key, OP_3, OP_CHECKMULTISIG]`

My suggested solution gives reference error.
I would be happy if anyone can help me.

Error:
{"error": "Error validating transaction: Rejected script for input 0 referencing 5f026fb3260c809d446740917bca4aa0e8633f64ec86fc8a4c5e23979f1578ba at 0.."}

Input script:
[OP_0, manager_sig,employee_sig]

Comment: Is the script you are looking for just doing `manager AND (employee_1 OR employee_2 OR employee_3)`? If so, you don't need to make such a complicated script or use the altstack. Is allowing any order a hard requirement? That severely complicates things, whereas if the scriptSig is just a template with signatures in a particular order, everything is a lot easier.

Comment: The order of signatures should not matter. So, the script should accept any order of signatures.

Comment: @cavitcakir OP_CHECKMULTISIG requires the signatures to be in the same order as the keys (though in case of a k-of-n, obviously sigs for some keys have to be omitted). Still, the remaining ones must be right.

Comment: @PieterWuille Yes, I know how it works so that's why I first check the order and do required manipulations. The first script works well when input is not ordered. But I used 2 my_public_key and I want to reduce the number of keys in the locking script.

Comment: @AndrewChow I forgot to mention you in the previous comment.